# parse Int not working for date function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing simple html control in select with hard codded date value and from this value I am splitting it in two part and from returned value I want to see day and month as an alert message,but it is showing me as a message of NaNNaN in alert instead of returning my formatted message.

```
<p>Click the button to display todays day of the month.</p>
<select id="account_type" name="account_type">

  <option value="1">Thursday May 29 at 2:00 PM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Friday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Monday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Saturday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>

</select>
<input type="image" id="submit" alt="Submit">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var str = $('#account_type option:selected').text();
    var spl = str.split("at");
    // alert("str : " + spl[0]);
    var d = new Date(spl[0]);
    var d1 = d.getDay();
    var d11 = parseInt(d1);
    var d2 = d.getMonth();
    var d12 = parseInt(d2);
    var d3 = d.getDate();
    var d13 = parseInt(d3);
    var fulldate = d11 + "" + d12;
    alert("Detail is : " + fulldate);
  });
});
```

Comment: `getDay()` and `getMonth()` returns numbers, why are you casting it ?

Comment: without casting i tried but still same error i am receiving

Comment: what should be the year

Comment: Because based on the locale/browser `new Date('Thursday May 29')` might return `InvalidDate` then `getDate()` and other getters will return NaN

Comment: @ArunPJohny, It doe not.. But it depends on the browser..

Comment: yes you might be right how to resolve if date is in such format

Comment: Can you `alert(new Date('Thursday May 29'))`

Comment: @Arun P Johny no alert is not working

Comment: Store the actual time in a machine readable format (e.g. unix timestamp) or the fulldate you want later directly in the `value=""` or in a `data-...=""` attribute in your `<option>`. Makes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your browser is parsing the date string as an `InvaliDate`.

One solution could be is to do a manual parsing of the string to date like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var months = {
      Jan: 0,
      Feb: 1,
      Mar: 2,
      Apr: 3,
      May: 4
    },
    days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    var str = $('#account_type option:selected').text();
    var spl = str.split(" ");

    //alert("str : "+spl[0]);

    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(months[spl[1]]);
    d.setDate(+spl[2]);

    var d0 = spl[0];
    var d1 = days[d.getDay()];
    var d2 = d.getMonth();
    var d3 = d.getDate();

    var fulldate = d0 + '-' + d1 + "-" + d2 + '-' + d3;

    alert("Detail is  : " + fulldate);



  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to display todays day of the month.</p>
<select id="account_type" name="account_type">

  <option value="1">Thursday May 29 at 2:00 PM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Friday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Monday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Saturday May 21 at 10:00 AM ET</option>

</select>
<input type="image" id="submit" alt="Submit">
```

Comment: how to set day value

Comment: picking only sunday despite of any you select

Comment: @delta12 did you see every where you have `may 22`(2016) which is a sunday

Comment: @delta12 if you just want to fetch the displayed value then see the update

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the text using "at" this keyword also in saturday s(at)urday
use some other character or word to split. I just modify your code try it!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
          var str = $('#account_type option:selected').text();
          var spl = str.split(",");
          // alert("str : "+spl[0]);
          var d = new Date(spl[0]);
          var d1 = d.getDay();
          var d11 = parseInt(d1);
          var d2 = d.getMonth();
          var d12 = parseInt(d2);
          var d3 = d.getDate();
          var d13 = parseInt(d3);
          var fulldate = d11 + " " + d12;
          alert("Detail is : " + fulldate);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Click the button to display todays day of the month.</p>
    <select id="account_type" name="account_type">
      <option value="1">Thursday May 29 , 2:00 PM ET</option>
      <option value="2">Tuesday May 22 , 10:00 AM ET</option>
      <option value="2">Friday May 22 , 10:00 AM ET</option>
      <option value="2">Monday May 22 , 10:00 AM ET</option>
      <option value="2">Wednesday May 22 , 10:00 AM ET</option>
      <option value="2">Saturday May 22 , 10:00 AM ET</option>
    </select>
    <input type="image" id="submit"  alt="Submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate `date` object in anyway you want, though your code will work in chrome as it is just more flexible but not in firefox. There are some specific formats and you should use them.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You need to mention a year in your date and then only it will work.

Try the following code:

```
<option value="1">Thursday May 29 2016 at 2:00 PM ET</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday May 22 2016 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
<option value="2">Friday May 22 2016 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
<option value="2">Monday May 22 2016 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
<option value="2">Wednesday May 22 2016 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
<option value="2">Saturday May 22 2016 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
```

I have just added `2016` in every `option`.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xszphg30/2/)

Comment: check the value for last option saturday? NaNaNa...no problem with format..https://jsbin.com/yefixojuro/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @nisar OP has just used sample dates. Check the last two dates, everything is same except the day he has used. Now a specific date can either be Wednesday or Saturday. And after checking my calendar May 22 2016 will be a Wed. So the last date is also invalid. :)

Comment: client don't want any year I can include on it they have different i/p for year  so option to include a year is not allowed in case.